# Is possible to make function from code and make it shorter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this lines of code

```
let value = productDetails.recentPurchaseDate;
if (!productDetails.salesPrice && !productDetails.recentPurchaseDate) {
  value = false;
}
if (!productDetails.presentEstimatedValue) {
  value = true;
}
```

Is it possible to refactor, I need to make it function and this two IF? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Make it clear` better than `make it smart`. It looks clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I don't think it is well designed if-conditions, but I don't know your business requirements. Let's try with something like this

```
let value = productHasRecentPurchaseDate(productDetails); //name should math your business goal

function productHasRecentPurchaseDate(productDetails) {
    if (!productDetails.salesPrice && !productDetails.recentPurchaseDate) {
       return false;
    }
    else if (!productDetails.presentEstimatedValue) {
       return true;
    }
    else {
        return /*you need all if statement path to return some value, this is last one, please provide what those statements should return if both previous conditions fail*/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function getValue({
    salesPrice,
    recentPurchaseDate,
    presentEstimatedValue
}) {
    if (!salesPrice && !recentPurchaseDate) return false;
    if (!presentEstimatedValue) return true
    return recentPurchaseDate
}
```

and then

```
let value = getValue(productDetails);
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: What is the kind of error you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```js
const value = yourNewFn();
function yourNewFn() {
    if (!productDetails.salesPrice && !productDetails.recentPurchaseDate) {
    value = false;
  }
  if (!productDetails.presentEstimatedValue) {
    value = true;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Then use this

```
if (!productDetails.salesPrice && !productDetails.recentPurchaseDate && !productDetails.presentEstimatedValue ) : value = false ? value = true;
```

Comment: This also does not work there is no else if

Comment: then use ternary operator 
if (!productDetails.salesPrice && !productDetails.recentPurchaseDate && !productDetails.presentEstimatedValue ) : value = false ? value = true;

Comment: This also does not work